# Efficently move multiple items in array from oldlocation to new location

Tags: arrays, algorithm, language-agnostic

For example suppose we have:

`a = [0,1,2,3,4];`

And suppose we want to move the element 1 and 2 after 4 so `a = [0,3,4,1,2]`. What we want to move from and to is given by the following data:

`oldLocation = [1,2]` #move item a[1] and a[2]

`newLocation = [3,4]` #move to a[3] and a[4]

Now notice the newLocation is relative to the original array `a`. So I can't just move one by one from old to new location, since the array would be modified. I need some special handling.

Any thoughts? Currently I'm making copy of array `a` and copying everything but the moved model. Then inserting the moved model at the specified position. Then setting `a` to the newly adjust array.

Language doesnt really matter, but I'm using javascript.

Comment: Why did you tag this with two languages that have nothing to do with the problem?

Comment: Was hoping more people could help, since some might only use the language filter to view question. Is that against the rule?

Comment: You're wasting a lot of people's time in the hopes that somebody not interested in javascript will decide to help you? Yeah, that's rude.

Comment: You need to do something that we do usually in a BubbleSort(Swapping). Assign the value of oldLoction[i] to temp, change oldLocation[i] to newLocation[i] and then change the newLocation[i] to temp. Notice that you don't need to loop through the array in order to do that.

Comment: @EricStein But this question is an algorithmic one not javascript?

Comment: That's what the algorithm tag is for. You just picked the two tags with the most users on them to try to get help from people who don't care about your kind of problem. Wasting their time is rude.

Answer (score 0):

```
int [] swap(int[] a, int[] oldl, int[] newl) {

    int len = oldl.length; // or newl.length
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int oldi = oldl[i];
        int newi = newl[i];

        int temp = a[oldi]; // swap both
        a[oldi] = a[newi];
        a[newi] = temp;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Please try to put effort & solve easier stuffs by yourself.

Comment: If you give him the answer, why should he put in any effort?

Comment: @Eric Stein Yup! u r correct, further will not help with code in similar scenarios.